# Custom domain bought from apphrbor deploying issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deployment, appharbor

I have recently bought a domain on appharbor and now I want to deploy my app on it. But it is not giving me any option to purchase it and when I open the domain i purchased it says dns address could not be found.
I already paid them for package fee

Comment: This is not a programming problem, instead it is a customer support problem and you should contact them about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated with programming problem, please contact your provider's customer support service for account details.